# Using backchannel with React Client - Bot framework

Tags: reactjs, botframework

I am using NodeJS to build a bot based on MS bot framework. I want to build the client with TypeScript + React, however, I want to be able to send messages once the user is logged in. By searching online, I figured I am able to do this using backchannel, as described in [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/backchannel/index.html) page.

However, I want to use it in React app, as described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/react/index.html)

I could make the React app work in my application, however I need to integrate the backchannel as well.

I don't understand why in every sample we're using something different. For example, in the React app, we're using `BotChat.Chat` .. but in the backchannel, we're using `BotChat.App` .. what's the difference between these two?

Also, I am going to use the backchannel in my React app, I would need to declare BotChannel and pass it to `BotChat.App`, how would this work in React where we're using `BotChat.Chat`?

Any example or clear documentation on these differences and how to implement backchannel with React will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to reference the chat later on you initialize your chat div something like this:

```
<div>
   <Chat ref={(chat) => {this._chat = chat;}} directLine={{ secret: "<secret>" }} user={{ id: 'user_id', name: 'user_name' }} />
</div>
```

The important part here is that you include a definition for ref like so:

```
ref={(chat) => {this._chat = chat;}}
```

After this is initialized you can access the botConnection later on via `this._chat.botConnection` and make `.postActivity()` calls like this:

```
this._chat.botConnection
    .postActivity({ type: "message", value: "hi", from: { id: "me" } })
    .subscribe(id => console.log("success"));
```

With regard to the difference between App and Chat, the quick way to put it is that App is a full modal while chat is broken down a little more for easier customization. App extends chat.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'll try this later this week and let you know.